# 8085 assembly instructions MOV, LDA and STA

Tags: assembly, copy, mov, 8085

I get the point of `MOV`, `STA` and `LDA` instructions, but what I don't understand is why are there three different instructions for two different processes?

- `STA` is for copying data from accumulator to memory location,
- `LDA` is for copying data from memory location to accumulator and
- `MOV` is for copying data between registers plus registers and memory.

So, what I can do with `STA` and `LDA` instructions can be done with `MOV` instruction too, right?

Comment: which processor are you using? assembly is quite vague. I know LDA & STA from 6502 but MOV doesn't exist, so must be another one.

Comment: 8080 probably.  MOV can't take an immediate address like LDA and STA can, it requires the address to be stored in HL.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre : 8085

Comment: @HansPassant MOV cannot take an immediate address but MVI can. But couldn't be there only two instructions: one for copying data from memory to any register or register pair, and another for copying data from any register or register pair to memory location? I mean, could there be only two in this case? I mean, I quite don't get the whole thing with data transfer though it sounds so simple...

Comment: MVI does not take an address, it takes an 8-bit value.  This is all hopelessly antiquated, there certainly is no "could be" anymore, don't waste your life on dinosaur technology.

Comment: It's partly just a question of designing the text assembly language.  e.g. x86 uses MOV for loads, stores, and mov-immediate.  Most assembly languages for RISC architectures use separate load and store mnemonics, but there's no reason they have to be that way.  In both cases, loads and stores have separate opcodes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The instructions `LDA` and `STA` move data between memory and `A`. The instruction `MOV` either moves data between registers, or between a register and a memory location specified by `HL`.

`LDA` and `STA` are used when the address can be resolved at assembly/link time.

`MOV` is used when the memory address is computed at run time, and is placed in `HL`. For example, when you are iterating through an array.

You have discovered *direct* and *indirect* memory addressing.

Comment: Thank you for you well defined explanation. It really helped me a lot in understanding of data movement instructions :D